# Consuming Third Party web services through Spring WebServiceTemplate

Tags: web-services, spring, wsdl, spring-ws, webservicetemplate

I'm trying to consume a Third Party web service, through a wsdl file provided. I would load the file locally from a Spring-J2EE based project underneath WEB-INF folder.

The wsdl might have more than one operation exposed. So I need a way to be able to choose the method to be called. I would also need to make use of a JaxbMarshaller.

Can anyone help with a code snippet for the same?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

WebServiceTemplate, and Spring-WS generally, do not treat WSDL as the starting point. Rather, it's schema-oriented.

When you use WebServiceTemplate, you plug in the JaxmMarshaller, then invoke the marshalSendAndReceiver methods, passing in a SoapActionCallback which contains the SOAP Action you want to invoke. You can get the SOAP action URI from the WSDL. WebServiceTemplate will marshal your request, wrap it in a WSDL envelope with the SOAP action you specified, and fire it off.

If you want a framework that generates stubs from your WSDL, then Spring-WS is not for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simple method for calling web service. For details [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26796149/how-to-consume-third-party-wsdl-services-in-spring-mvc)

```
public void createSoapActionCallBack(ValidateCardRequest validateCardRequest) {

        //This is used to send header message
        SoapActionCallback actionCallBack=new SoapActionCallback(soapAction);
        try{

            actionCallBack = new SoapActionCallback(SOAPACTION_DEFAULT_URL) {
            public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage msg) {
                    SoapMessage smsg = (SoapMessage)msg;                
                    SoapHeader soapHeader = smsg.getSoapHeader();

                    try{
                        //To send header message
                        StringSource headerSource = new StringSource("<UserCredentials xmlns='URL'>\n" +
                                        "<userid>"+"ABCD"+"</userid>\n" +
                                        "<password>"+"ABCD"+"</password>\n" +
                                        "</UserCredentials>");
                        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
                        transformer.transform(headerSource, soapHeader.getResult());

                        smsg.setSoapAction(soapAction);
                    }catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                }; 
               validateCardResponse = (FVValidateCardResponse) webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(URL, validateCardRequest, actionCallBack);  

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }       
}
```